# Why do these Visual Studio 2017 Optimisations Cause An Error?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Originally, I was creating a SQL parameter like so:

```
Dim FileData As New SqlParameter("@FileData", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1)
FileData.Value = DBNull.Value
```

VS2017 then suggested that I simplify it to:

```
Dim FileData As New SqlParameter("@FileData", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1) With {
    .Value = DBNull.Value
}
```

So, I apply it. VS2017 then suggested that I simplify it *AGAIN* to:

```
Dim FileData As New SqlParameter("@FileData", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1) With {
    DBNull.Value
}
```

So, again, I apply it. But now it comes up with an error:

```
Error   BC30985 Name of field or property being initialized in an object initializer must start with '.'.
```

Firstly, am I gaining anything by any of these "simplifications"? The original seems pretty simple already.

Secondly, why is VS2017 recommending something to me which results in an error?

Is it possible to fix this error, whilst also adhering to the suggested simplification? Or should I just suppress the warnings regarding the simplifications and stick with my original statement?

I know it probably doesn't matter either way, just asking out of curiosity.

Thanks.

Comment: The compiled result of the code will be the same either way. You're not really gaining anything in this case but if you had multiple properties to set then the first suggestion would be neater. The second suggestion may only apply to C#, so having it recommended in VB code may be a mistake.

Comment: Nobody can tell you the reason for the suggestions except Microsoft. I personally would ignore those silly suggestions. As you stated, your version looks better than the suggested one. Those are only code difference for human readers, the compiled code is identical for the computer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The 2nd suggestion is possible to use in VB, but I think only for anonymous objects, so intellisense may have a bug :P

Comment: @Jaxi, it appears that it's not valid for C# as is either.

Comment: It seems to be a bug with the "IDE0037:Use inferred member name" messages: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23659 "The fix should ship in 15.6 preview 3."

Comment: In practice these code analysis messages are meant to help programmers discover new language features.  Given that they do so little to make code faster or more readable.  They do get in the way, especially when they get it wrong of course, resist the urge to have that light-bulb tell you what to do.  It tends to be too visible if you use a dark color scheme.

Comment: @HansPassant In fairness, yes... in certain circumstances I will now use the "with" syntax, whereas I probably wouldn't before. So in that respect, it has done it's job... just a shame it's still a bit buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with Visual Studio.

Specifically, the "IDE0037:Use inferred member name" messages.

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/23659 - "The fix should ship in 15.6 preview 3."